# Apache: http2 push assets loaded two times

Tags: php, apache, http, http2

I've configured a Windows Apache web server with http2.

I've enabled the module

```
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
```

And in the vhost I've added:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <IfModule mod_http2.c>
      Protocols h2 http/1.1
    </IfModule>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I create this example page in php:

```
<?php
   header('Link: </test.js>; rel=preload; as=script', false);
   header('Link: </test.css>; rel=preload; as=style', false);
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But chrome console shows me that these files are downloaded 2 times.

[image]

Following are listed header sent by server. I use Apache 2.4.25

[image]

Is this a normal behaviour?

Is this the correct configuration?

Comment: No it's not normal, and no it's not correct. It should show "Push" under the initiator. I have seen this sort of thing when the "as" is not specified but you nhave specified it. Can you try removing the spaces in case that is causing an issue (so 'Link: </test.css>;rel=preload;as=style')?

Comment: Hmmm tested it and the spaces don't matter. Curious. What version of Apache are you using? Can you show your link header that is sent to the browser?

Comment: I edit my post with headers and apache version